# is there a better way to display results other than using echo

Tags: php

I posted in a previous question how to get my rating script to work. I have now finally got it to work using maths rather than the avg function but i still have two questions to ask.

Q1) Is there a better way of displaying my results other than using echo all the time

Q2) How do i add in my other three performance values in to this script they are all in the same table

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ("sorry we could not connect to our servers");
mysql_select_db("db") or die ("sorry we could not our database");

$find_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rating");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_data))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$current_rating = $row['Reliability_timekeeping'];
$reviews = $row['reviews'];
$new_rating = $current_rating / $reviews;
echo "($reviews Reviews)";
echo "Reliability & timekeeping: ";
echo round($new_rating,1);
echo "/10";
}
?>
```

sorry for my writing skill writing is not my strong point and still new to php

Comment: You can use a [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Probably one of the best things since sliced bread.

Comment: lol what does heredoc do does that replace echo or does it let me use my other 3 performance to this script

Comment: @user3907336 http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I included a link to it in my first comment; reload. There's also `nowdoc` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: If you're going to use heredoc, make absolutely sure that there is nothing before or after the closing identifier, also nothing after the opening identifier. [Read the docs on it.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: You can also do `echo "Your code in here" . $variable . " starting up again with text" . $another_variable . " put a bunch of carriage returns.....` then finish it off with a `end of text";` which only uses one echo.

Comment: Please dont use heredoc. it's sloppy, and it makes your code Extremely hard to interpret and maintain

Comment: i going to sound really stupid here but fred ii but i looked at the heredoc and it gone right over my head it just made me more confused is there any easyer way for beginners

Comment: It's not stupid, have a look at `Marcovecchio's` answer below. The logic sort of resembles what I posted [`as a comment here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167960/is-there-a-better-way-to-display-results-other-than-using-echo#comment39185176_25167960). It's the stupid ones that don't ask ;)

Comment: so the little code marcovecchio's used would i just add in my other performance part and just change the $Response for each other part of the my script or does it come all under the $response value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using echo all the time, you can just accumulate all the output in a variable and use a single echo. As a good practice, in my scripts I try to use just one echo at the script end. This will make each page a few mili-seconds faster, as less PHP / web server interactions will be necessary:

```
$Response = "";
$Response .= "($reviews Reviews)".
             "Reliability & timekeeping: ".round($new_rating,1)."/10";

...
more code
...

echo $Response;
```

Just indent and break lines in a way that the code gets readable, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Funny you posted this; I wrote something to that effect in a comment at the same time you were putting this together lol. [`Check it out`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167960/is-there-a-better-way-to-display-results-other-than-using-echo#comment39185176_25167960)

Comment: so let me see if i get this right if i was to use this way would this be the way it would work

Comment: $Response = "";
    $Response .= "($reviews Reviews)".
             "Reliability & timekeeping:     ".round($new_rating,1)."/10";

"tidiness:     ".round($new_rating,1)."/10";
echo $Response;

Comment: The only bit you have to correct is this: `.../10"."tidiness...`. Use dots between each fragment. The dot is used to concatenate strings in PHP. And it works all in one line, but I prefer to break into several lines and indent / align correctly, to make it more readable.

Comment: i have changed my code to use your code how would i add images in to the code do i use the html tag <img> and how do i line break do i have to use the <br/> tag or is there a better way

Comment: @user3907336: it would be better to create new questions for these, but yes, the <img> tag is your primary choice for images. About line breaks, there are several approaches, and <br> is fine for breaking lines on a continuous text flow, but if you want to add vertical spacing between different elements (like a title and some text), you should learn how to use CSS, to apply styles to each semantically different block. The breaks and exact spacing can be defined on CSS rules, which will be separate from your markup, and that is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template engine that fills your data in to a template that you can write like HTML with some additional placeholders. A template engine has some great advantages over echoing out the values:

- separate code from layout
- reusable
- better maintainability and readability

Here are some of the template engines I used in PHP, they also have good documentation to get you started:

- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)